# VS2017 Build error - The command nuget restore exited with code 9009

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, nuget

When i am bulding my project i see the below error.

> The command "nuget restore ProjectName.csproj - PackagesDirectory
> ....\packages" exited with 9009.

When i clicked edit on my .csproj i see below lines of code

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      <Exec WorkingDirectory ="$(ProjDir)" command = "nuget restore $(ProjectName) -PackagesDirectory
 ..\..\packages>
</Exec>
</Target>
```

Comment: Please check if you download the latest `nuget.exe cli` and then config its path into System environment variable `PATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, you should make sure that you have downloaded [the latest nuget.exe  v5.7.0](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and config it full path into System Environment **PATH**.

**1)** download it and copy it into a folder

[image]

**2)** then open System Environment Variable **PATH** and config the path of local `nuget.exe` into it.

[image]

Then, click all **Ok** option to save it.

**After that**, you can open **CMD** and type `nuget` to check whether it can call `nuget.exe`.

**Second**, close all vs instance or msbuild window, open your `xxx.csproj` file of your project，

**Instead**, use this:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" command = "nuget restore $(MSBuildProjectFile) -PackagesDirectory ..\packages ">
    </Exec>
</Target>
```

**Restart your project**, or close to reawaken MSBuild to build your project.

It works well in my side.

Comment: changing the .csproj file might impact other users when i check in the code ?

Comment: i tried changing the system environment variable path and opened cmd and typed nuget, it gives a message 'nuget is not recognized as an internal or external command'... while adding the system environment variable i have given the variable name as 'nuget'

Comment: i have downloded nuget.exe and copied it to c:Windows folder and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. And that indicates that you have not configured the `nuget.exe` into your agent so that the command won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded nuget.exe from https://www.nuget.org/downloads and copied it to C drive Windows folder, it worked.