# NuGet returns 'Package integrity checks' on freshly downloaded packages

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I've never worked with VS and .NET before and I don't have much programming experience overall either (am a QA by trade, only gotten into test automation recently, which might explain the format of this question to you ;)), so I'm a bit out of my element here. I've tried all ideas that came to my mind and those that I saw in Google but still can't fix this on my own.

### Steps

1. Fresh install of VS 2019 via VS Installer from MS
2. Clone repository from Bitbucket via VS; the repo includes a dependency on system.IO and System.Linq
3. Attempt to Build Solution

### Error result

Error   NU3008  Package 'System.Linq 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The package integrity check failed.
Error   NU3008  Package 'System.IO 4.3.0' from source
'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The package integrity check failed.

It works for a coworker, even if he checks out some code changes that I push out while having this error.

#### Attempted fixes

Delete caches through NuGet package manager UI, change to a different branch and see if it works there, remove and re-clone the repo, reinstall VS, update packages, wipe everything related to VS and .NET then reinstall, manually remove the System.io and System.linq DLLs then rebuild or update packages, modify components installed with VS, delete everything from %userprofile%.nuget\packages to force NuGet to redownload everything. Nothing helped.

My intuition is that the signature shipped from NuGet is out of date somehow? Since when I remove all local packages, clean cache, then make a new, clean project, literally with only 'Hello World' that auto-generates, and then only try to install the System.IO or System.Linq packages manually via package manager, I get the same error.

#### The question

Is there anything I can do here, something on my side that might be causing this, or do I need to contact NuGet?

Comment: That's something to do with the authenticity of the signed package - meaning that it thinks the package has been tampered with. I'm wondering if the package might have been slightly altered via some anti-virus immedialty after download or perhaps the files are ending up in the 'Blocked' state on your system. As a first step maybe grab a copy of the packages that your colleagues are using and transfer them to your project via flash drive. If those work then compare those ones with your original and take it from there.

Comment: @MarkRabjohn somehow we never got the idea to do that :D thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu3008) said,

run `nuget locals http-cache -clear` and `nuget locals -Clear all` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**.

**Besides**, if it does not work, please try these:

**1)** close VS, delete `nuget.config` file from `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`,

delete `.vs` hidden folder of the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of the project,

and then restart VS to regenerate that file to check whether it works.

**2)** change your `nuget.org` package source as `http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/` like this:

[image]

**3)** copy the nuget packages `System.IO` and `System.Linq` from your worked coworker's PC into your `%userprofile%.nuget\packages`. And then reinstall your nuget package there to check if this work.

**4)** download the latest `nuget.exe v5.7.0` from [this link](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and then configure it local path into System Environment Variable **PATH** so that it will be called from **CMD**.

**You** can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711576/vs2017-build-error-the-command-nuget-restore-exited-with-code-9009/63716356#63716356) about the step.

**Then**, close VS and then restart your project, run these under **Package Manager Console**:

```
 nuget restore
```

**5)** Last, doing a clean uninstall might not be a good decision but it's worth a try.

Find `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe` and run this program.

**Note**: it will uninstall all **VS2017** and **VS2019** versions on your PC and make a deep clean environment. If you don't mind these, you can run it.

**When** you finishing it, you can run the `vs_installer` to reinstall it. And after the installation, you can check the issue still persists.

Comment: Thank you! I've already removed caches before, as per the documentation, but your first suggestion with nuget.config seems to have helped.

Comment: Glad to know that it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands and then run restore again after:

```
  nuget locals http-cache -clear
```

or

```
dotnet nuget locals http-cache --clear
```