# Building and running unit tests with Visual Studio build tools

Tags: c++, visual-studio, continuous-integration, nuget

I am adding unit tests to an existing C++ Visual Studio projects, using the Google Test adapter.

It's all running fine on my computer with Visual Studio 2019, but when I try to run them on the build server I get the following error

> error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.1.3\build\native\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.targets.

However, we're not using NuGet for package management. I tried installing it but complained about missing folders. This is not a .NET project, so I think that's a red herring.

I was able to install the Google Test adapter on my computer using the Visual Studio Installer, but it does not show up as a part of the VS Build Tools on the build server.

Running `msbuild -t:restore` does not help, it just reports "nothing to do."

I don't understand why the Google Test adapter isn't available for VS Build Tools, since it seems to be required in order to build the unit tests. Does anyone know why it doesn't work? What's the best practice for handling this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your c++ project has missed the content of **googletest** nuget package. So the solution is to restore the whole nuget package in your c++ project.

**Update 1**

**First of all, take a brand new backed up project and restore it to when the problem started.**

**Besides**, `msbuild -t:restore` command applies to projects with [PackageReference nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files).

**Since** your c++ project used [packages.config nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config), `msbuild -t:restore` will not work. [See this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-target).**Instead**, you should use `nuget restore` command.

This command works for your current project and running this command will restore the nuget packages and then you will never face the issue.

**Before using it**, you should download nuget.exe CLI and config its path into System Environment Variable **PATH** so that **CMD** can invoke `nuget`.

The steps about configing `nuget.exe`, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711576/vs2017-build-error-the-command-nuget-restore-exited-with-code-9009/63716356#63716356).

**Steps**

**1)** delete `packages` folder under the solution folder

[image]

**2)Then**, open build tool, run:

```
nuget restore xxx\xxx\xxx.sln(the full path of solution file containing the c++ project and the unit test project)
```

**Then**, you can build the project with the command. And I hope the error will disappear.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the procedure did not work, I still get the same error on the build server

Comment: Since you used build tool to build the project rather than VS IDE. So the above steps might not work. Besides, `msbuild -t:restore` does not work for the c++ project with `packages.config`  nuget management format. Instead, you should run `nuget restore` to restore the c++ nuget packages on your build server. I have updated my answer and you can check it.

Comment: Thanks, it works with nuget... I had hoped that msbuild would be able to do all the things visual studio can do but I guess not. At least it works now