# MSBuild and VS2019 reference resolving difference

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution with multiple projects.
The solution has projects in both C # and VB.
The solution has SDK-style and non-SDK-style projects.

I uses VS2019. It builds the solution without any errors.

My build server is using MSBuild from VS2019 build tools. It founds [CS0246](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246) errors in my solution.

Examining the code shows that the problem is the missing project reference. Project dependency hierarchy is shown below:

```
A  - SDK-style C# project
| 
+-> B  - Non-SDK-style VB project 
    |
    +-> C  - SDK-style C# project
```

The code from project A uses classes from project C. But project A doesn't have project C in its ProjectReference list. It is an error without doubt.

**But why VS2019 does not detect CS0246 error?**

**What should I change in my VS2019 so that it gives me exactly the same build results as the build server?**

Version of MSBuild is the same 16.8.2.56705 on build server and on my PC.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues

Comment: Yes. It looks like very old msbuild bug: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/417

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I did not face the same issue in my side.

In my test project,

**Project A**(a new-sdk style net472 console project）which has a **ProjectReference** to **Project B**(a vb net framework 4.7.2 class library project) like this:

Use `ProjectReference`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectB\ProjectB.vbproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**While** Project B also has a **ProjectReference** to Project C(new-sdk net472 class library project):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectC\ProjectC.csproj">
      <Project>{bf3ad507-ed99-486a-b90d-51d8acc25dfc}</Project>
      <Name>ProjectC</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**In my side**, I also uses the function from **Project C** into **Project A** and it builds with any errors.

**In fact**, **Project A** can obtain the content of **Project C** through the transfer relationship. The build order is `C`, `B`, `A`. **A** first visits **B** to find the method of **C**. When the reference to **C** in **B** is read, there is access to the project of **C**, so the method of **C** is obtained. Therefore, there is no need for **A** to have a reference to **C**. As long as the order of the dependent layers is correct, there will be no problem.

**Then**, I passed the whole solution to the build server and then it works well.

So please try the following suggestions:

**1)** make sure that your build tool has installed the related workload such as `.NET Desktop build tool`,`Net Core build tool`, also the related Net Framework version.

**2)** delete every project's `bin` and `obj` folder on the build sever

**3)** use Build Tool, first restore and then build.

```
cd xxx\xxx.sln
 msbuild -t:restore,build
```

**If** your VB project has other nuget packages, you should use [nuget restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330497/building-and-running-unit-tests-with-visual-studio-build-tools/64345899#64345899) additionally:

```
 cd xxx\xxx.sln
 nuget restore
 msbuild -t:restore,build
```

**Besides**, if it does work for your issue, please share a small sample here which will help us investigate this issue more efficiently.

**Update**

Project A:

```
using System;
using ProjectC;
namespace ProjectA
{
    public class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test te = new Test();
           

            Console.WriteLine(te.Tec(3, 5));

            Console.WriteLine(te.Test1());
        }

    }
}
```

Project C:

```
using System;

namespace ProjectC
{
    public class Test
    {
        private int a, b;
        public int Tec(int a,int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

    }
}
```

**Project A** references **Project B** , **B** references **C**. And **A** uses the function from **C**.

**Screenshot**

I moved the solution into build sever, and then delete `.vs`, every `bin` and `obj` folder and then run these commands, no error occours.

[image]

**Maybe** there is something wrong with your build sever. Please click `Repair` from VS Installer for the build tool. Or just reinstall build tool.

Comment: There is no problem with nuget packages. And there is no problem with the build server.
In fact in my case VS2019 does not behave correctly. VS2019 allows me to import and use classes from projects that are not referred directly in the project file. Since both VS2019 and the build server use MSBuild of the same version, the problem is somewhere in the VS2019-MSBuild integration.

Comment: Did you try to add `<PropertyGroup>  <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle> </PropertyGroup> ` on the `projectB.vbproj` file since it is a non-sdk style project?

Comment: According to documentation (https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/blob/master/docs/consume-packages/Package-References-in-Project-Files.md) PackageReference option is used for nuget packages. My case does not relate to packages.

Comment: Anyway I inserted suggested fragment in projectB project file. Unfortunately I did not notice any difference: VS2019 still considers the wrong code correct.

Comment: I create a solution, project a references project b , b references c. And a uses the function from c. When I migrate the solution into the build sever and build the project by build tool, it could works well without any issues. So I am curious about the issue. And in fact, it is not an issue and project A can gets project C by Project B. Maybe there is something wrong with your build sever. Please click `Repair` from VS Installer for the build tool. Or just reinstall build tool.

Comment: Or you could share your sample with us to help us troubleshoot the issue further.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was fixed in [VS 16.8.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.8.4):

> Issued Addressed in this Release of Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8.4:
>
> Transitive project references are now respected when a PackageReference projects >references packages.config projects with PackageReference dependencies.

We had the same issue and now it works fine.