# How can I get MSBuild to restore any needed NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I've looked at a ton of articles on this including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956184/msbuild-and-package-restore-with-packages-config) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets). None provide a solution that I can get to work.

I have everything turned on for automatically doing this in VisualStudio. But on our build machine we build the .sln files using MSBuild, not by opening up VisualStudio. So in MSBuild how can I best do this?

All of our .sln files are for VisualStudio 2019 and set to defaults on handling NuGet (I believe).

Comment: Based on the actual project type you need either `nuget.exe restore` or `msbuild /t:restore`. Has been widely discussed.

Comment: @LexLi I tried "msbuild myfile.proj /t:restore" and it completes instantly doing nothing. And I have not been able to find where I can download nuget.exe from.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/downloads You might study why MSBuild doesn't work by reading its bin log, https://msbuildlog.com/

Comment: @DavidThielen, any update about this issue?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I ended up doing the "nuget restore filename.sln"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`msbuild -t:Restore` will restore nuget packages for projects with [PackageReference nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files).

And your situation looks like [packages.config nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config) which you have used it.

If so, you only should use `nuget restore` to restore nuget packages with msbuild.exe.

**1)** first download `nuget.exe cli` from the website and config it. You can check [this about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711576/vs2017-build-error-the-command-nuget-restore-exited-with-code-9009/63716356#63716356).

**2)** then use MSBuild command line, type

```
nuget xxx\xxx.sln restore
msbuild xxx\xxx.sln -t:build
```

Another is to use msbuild -t:restore with `-p:RestorePackagesConfig=true`.

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.sln -t:restore,build -p:RestorePackagesConfig=true
```

Comment: It's actually `nuget restore xxx\xxx.sln`

Comment: NB this MS article explicitly explains not to use `-t:restore,build` like you have here but to use `-t:build -restore` - Reason given is:

`Due to the fact that NuGet can restore packages that bring down MSBuild targets and props, the restore and build evaluations are run with different global properties. This means that the following will have an unpredictable and often incorrect behavior.`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restoring-and-building-with-one-msbuild-command